# Nginx config works with angularjs route in HTML5 mode

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angularjs, nginx

I am struggling with the nginx config file with angularjs route.

In my case, I have these HTMLs:

`index.html`
`description.html`
`dashboard.html`

The `dashboard.html` is the one with angularjs code.

Here is my current nginx config file:

```
upstream panda.dev {
    server 127.0.0.1:3333 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  panda.dev;
    root /Users/Jeremy/Documents/Projects/PandaUnion/web/converted-html;

    # serve static files directly
    location / {
        index index.html$args;
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri/ /dashboard.html$args =404;
    }
}
```

Here is my angular code:

```
PandaUnion.controller('PandaController', function($routeParams, $location) {
  console.log($routeParams);
});

var templateURL = '/partials';

PandaUnion.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  return $routeProvider.when('/dashboard/:user_id', {
    templateUrl: templateURL + '/home.html'
  }).when('/dashboard/:user_id/setting', {
    templateUrl: templateURL + '/setting.html'
  }).when('/dashboard/:user_id/bill', {
    templateUrl: templateURL + '/bill.html'
  });
});
```

With this config, I can get `dashboard.html` via visiting `/dashboard/123`, but I can't get `123` as routeParam in angular.

It should print `{user_id: 123}` when I visit `/dashboard/123` but I only see an empty Object.

What goes wrong here? Please help...

(sorry for my poor English)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the AngularJS [tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07). As you can see there, you have to bind the parameter (user_id in your case) via the $routeParams object.

So:

1. Define a controller for the when() statements
2. Inject the $routeParams object in that controller
3. Bind the parameters to the $scope object
4. In your template make sure you are within the controller boundaries when referring to "user_id"

Hope that helps.